# Disabling the Cache - chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser-cache

I am making changes to my MERN app (on my mac).

Each time, I save, restart the server, and expect the changes to be recognised. A change could be a simple as adding another letter to a label in the html (although what i really want to see is changes to the CSS).

However, the typing changes aren't reflected when I render localhost 3000. I can't understand why. I have disabled the cache in the network tab on chrome. I can't figure out why these changes aren't populating. This is true even if I restart my computer.

How can I get the server restart to pick up changes?

Comment: [This works for me](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn)

Comment: I have browsers in safari, chrome and firefox. I have disabled the cache in chrome, wiped it in Firefox and refreshed every hour (and shut down and restarted the server at least 20 times) over the last 2 days and I still can't get a typo correction to render. How can I get the refresh to load?

Comment: Do all three browsers have the same problem?

Comment: yes - in each browser - i can't get any of them to render the current code

Comment: It may be that your server is serving a cached copy. (I actually know very little about this)

Comment: Does the issue persist if you open an new incognito window in chrome? - please note I said window and not just an incognito tab.

Comment: Yes - I have chrome windows open in normal and incognito modes. How many days is the expected wait time for the server to refresh after you force a refresh?

Comment: if the cache is cleared on the server and you open it in an incognito window you should see the changes right away.